# Error in creating active RAR + ResourceAdapterImpl class not found in JAVA

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish, ejb, dbconnection

I have created a EJB package with Glassfish V 4.0 and postgre sql as server and DB respectively. Glassfish and postgre are installed remotely.

I have created a connection pool and JNDI

Let me know if any more details is required

When i run my class file it gives me following error

```
Dec 17, 2013 10:47:16 AM com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ActiveRAFactory   
createActiveResourceAdapter

SEVERE: RAR6001 : Class Not found : com.sun.gjc.spi.ResourceAdapterImpl
Dec 17, 2013 10:47:16 AM com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ActiveRAFactory  
createActiveResourceAdapter
SEVERE: 
com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Error in creating  
active RAR
at  com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ActiveRAFactory.createActiveResourceAdapter(ActiveRAFactory.java:111)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ResourceAdapterAdminServiceImpl.createActiveResourceAdapter(ResourceAdapterAdminServiceImpl.java:210)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.createActiveResourceAdapter(ConnectorRuntime.java:427)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.naming.ConnectorObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(ConnectorObjectFactory.java:107)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getObjectInstance(SerialContext.java:527)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:487)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at sg.edu.astar.taxi360.dao.impl.DBConnection.<clinit>(DBConnection.java:24)
at sg.edu.astar.taxi360.dao.dummy.main(dummy.java:22)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.gjc.spi.ResourceAdapterImpl
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ActiveRAFactory.createActiveResourceAdapter(ActiveRAFactory.java:102)
... 10 more
```

My class file which has main method

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    dummy p = new dummy();
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    String sql="";
    try(Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();)
    {
        sql = "INSERT INTO databasename.request (requestId)" +
            "VALUES (?)";
        stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setString(1, "1324");
        stmt.executeQuery();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){

    }
}
```

DBConnection class file contains following details

```
public class DBConnection {
    private static DataSource ds;
    static {
        try {
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/databasename");
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
        }
    }


    public static Connection getConnection() {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = ds.getConnection();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding `glassfish-embedded-all` to my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```